# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on Vaadin 8 Addons

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, add-on

Im trying to use Open Layers on my Vaadin 8 project. I added the Maven dependency on my POM.xml and checked if this addon is compatible with version 8. But even so I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. What I am doing wrong? This is happening with others addons compatible with Vaadin 8 also...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vaadin/addon/vol3/source/OLSource
at com.nathan.views.Home.lambda$3(Home.java:189)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:211)
at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:174)
at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1033)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:370)
at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1568)
at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:381)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.vaadin.addon.vol3.source.OLSource
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:428)
    ... 53 more

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.nathan</groupId>
<artifactId>projetocibus</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>projetocibus</name>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <vaadin.version>8.1.4</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>8.1.4</vaadin.plugin.version>
    <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <!-- If there are no local customisations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
    <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencias incluidas pelo programador  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shiro/shiro-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vaadin.icons/vaadin-icons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.icons</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-icons</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.steinwedel.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>messagebox</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.liveimageeditor</groupId>
        <artifactId>live-image-editor</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.maxschuster</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-autocompletetextfield</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-storage -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sendgrid/sendgrid-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencias do JASPER -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- fim das dependencias do jasper -->
    <!-- Open Layers Map  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addon</groupId>
        <artifactId>v-ol3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Tomcat plugin -->  
        <plugin>  
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>  
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>2.2</version>  
            <configuration>  
                <url>xxxxx</url>  
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <username>xxxxx</username>  
                <password>xxxxx</password>   
            </configuration>   
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update-theme</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                        <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/styles.css</include>
                            <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
            running jetty:run on the command line. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.58</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
        <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Can you attach `pom` also?

Comment: open layers <dependency> is the last one on <dependencies>

Comment: This: _This is happening with others addons compatible with Vaadin 8 also._ is it only about `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/vaadin/addon/vol3/source/OLSource` or some other classes also?

Comment: If other class defs missing too put few examples.

Comment: How are you running your application when you're getting the error?

Comment: For example, if I change the Open Layers to Google Maps, I got the same kind of error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/tapio/googlemaps/GoogleMap

Comment: Another information, I'm not using the compatibility variants of vaadin-server dependency neither vaadin-client dependency, and I think thats the issue..

Comment: Im running on Jetty server locally... @morfic

Comment: @NathanMachado did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I partialy resolved this. In the case of maps I created a custom javascript component extending the AbstractJavaScriptComponent base class and implemented my own JavaScript library. Becuse of that, I stopped trying to use the addon. But the problem of using some addons in Vaadin 8 I couldn't find the cause until now.

Answer (score 0):

Just check are you able to access the jars used for the addons in repositories folder if not accesible then just download from the maven respository with the correct version of the addon you are looking for paste in your repository and try again..!!